# How to build a nested list from a flat one in Python?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a flat list, for example:

```
flat = ['1', '1-1', '1-1-1', '1-2', '2', '2-1', '2-2', '3']
```

that I need to convert to a nested list, where each level (dash followed by a number) starts a new sublist, for example:

```
result = ['1', ['1-1', ['1-1-1'], '1-2'], '2', ['2-1', '2-2'], '3']
```

Any tips how to do that in Python?

Comment: Did you Google "Depth-First Search" yet?  It will be difficult to do with SOPA protests.  But you should carefully read what you can about depth-first search.  Also.  If this is Homework, please tag it properly

Comment: I will do the reading on Depth-First Search and `itertools`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def nested(flat, level=0):
    for k, it in itertools.groupby(flat, lambda x: x.split("-")[level]):
        yield next(it)
        remainder = list(nested(it, level + 1))
        if remainder:
            yield remainder
```

Example:

```
>>> list(nested(flat, 0))
['1', ['1-1', ['1-1-1'], '1-2'], '2', ['2-1', '2-2'], '3']
```